# How to make an HTML grid scroll horizontally as well as vertically?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am generating a grid dynamically like so:

```js
function createGrid(numberOfRows) {
  document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = "";
  console.log(numberOfRows);
  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
    var divRow = document.createElement("div");
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(divRow);
    for (let y = 0; y < numberOfRows; y++) {
      let divCol = document.createElement("div");
      divRow.appendChild(divCol);
    }

  }
}
window.onload = createGrid(10)
```

```css
#container {
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

#container>div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
}

#container>div>div {
  float: left;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 25px;
}

div {
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

This works perfectly if the grid fully fits on the screen:
[image: properly displayed grid]

but breaks if the grid is bigger (for example with createGrid(100)):
[image: broken grid]

How do I make the grid display properly (as a square with a horizonal scrollbar)?

Comment: Just having `div { display: table; }` is not enough - you must also style elements in the hierarchy below. Rows as `table-row` and cells as (`table-cell`). See [MDN - CSS - display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#internal)

Comment: Consider just using actual table/tr/td elements, if the sample code is representative of what you're actually doing. Alternatively, look into using an actual CSS grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use floats, use `display: grid` for displaying a grid.

In my solution I set the cells of the grid as inline style and use this then in CSS to define how many cells there should be in a row.

```js
function createGrid(numberOfRows) {
  const container = document.getElementById('container');
  document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = "";
  container.setAttribute('style', `--cells: ${numberOfRows} `);
  console.log(numberOfRows);
  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
    for (let y = 0; y < numberOfRows; y++) {
      let divCell = document.createElement("div");
      container.appendChild(divCell);
    }

  }
}
window.onload = createGrid(100)
```

```css
#container {
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 25px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--cells), 25px);
}

#container>div {
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: this works perfectly for all sizes

Answer (score 0):

You are using `display: table` but with `display: grid` and `grid-auto-flow` property, it should work. Try the below css.

```
#container {
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    display: grid;   
    grid-auto-flow: row; 
}

#container > div {
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;   
    grid-auto-flow: column;  
}

#container > div > div {
    float: left;
    height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 25px;
}
```

Comment: this works for large grids, but when the grid fits on the screen it doesn't!